# Update a data in SQL database

Tags: java, sql

I have a table in my database. I am using jdbc to use this database. I want to update a particular data by subtracting it to some value.

Suppose a student with name xyz is there. Currently his marks in a subject is 50. I want to delete it by 10, then what would be the syntax? I am new to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less:

```
update students
   set mark = mark - 10
 where name = 'xyz'
```

Can't give a better answer than that, as your question is very limited in useful and concrete information. I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: thanx man...but have a quetion...is it possible to give column name as a variable...that is if there are 3 columns marks1, marks2 and marks3...and if a variable temp is there whose value is decide at run time whether it will be marks1 or 2 or 3...wil the statement " update students set students.temp = students.temp - 10 where name = 'xyz' " work?

Comment: @huk: you can assemble the SQL query in Java first, so it uses one of the `marks` columns you refer to. However, if you have several marks columns, it sounds like you need to split this table into two, so that you have only one marks column.